# How to find who created .png file and remove the author on MAC?

Tags: security, png, metadata

For security reasons, I want to have .png files without an author in the metadata.

1. How do I check who is the author of the .png file on Mac?
2. How do I remove the author on .png file on Mac?

I check for the information on *Preview*, but it only contains information like camera type, pixels, etc. but not the author.

Comment: So how do you know "the author" is in metadata? Add an example of such an image to your question.

Comment: I don't know, it's an assumption that it has to be somewhere in metadata. How can I find the author then?

Comment: Consider the possibility that your assumption is wrong, and the reason you cannot find it means that it isn't there.

Comment: Does it mean that .png files don't contain the author?

Comment: They might, as PNG files indeed can contain metadata (per the [official specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/)). I can add a free text block and put my name in it. But there is no standard for that.

Comment: Correct me if I am right then. If the author is not shown on Preview, it means there is no way to extract this information?

Comment: No, it'd only means that *Preview* does not show it. If that is all you're worried about, you are done. Other tools may or may not show more information.

Answer (score 2):

Using [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) in terminal, you can see all the embedded metadata by running exiftool on the file
`exiftool /path/to/file.png`

You can remove the embedded metadata with the command
`exiftool -all= /path/to/file.png`

A couple things to take note of.  While the PNG format supports a wide range of metadata, support for metadata in PNG files is very poor/non-existent in a lot of programs/apps.  The results is that very few PNG files have any metadata embedded in them.

Also, on a Mac, there is a lot of metadata that will appear in when looking at the file properties (`XAttr`/`MDItem`) that are part of the Mac file system, not embedded in the file.  This data will be lost if the file is uploaded to a website or copied to a non-Mac drive.  The above exiftool commands will not edit this data, so you have to look for a different program to remove such data.